# Yocto is ignoring my bbappend when trying to modify another layer's file

Tags: bitbake, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I made my own custom layer. The bbappend I added is to reference a u-boot.env custom file I am trying to use to modify another layer's .env file.

The following is my bbappend and file structure:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${BP}:"
```

File structure:

```
└── u-boot
    ├── u-boot-karo_2022.04
    │   ├── defconfigs
    │   │   └── mx8mp-nxp-bsp
    │   └── env
    │       └── qsxp-ml81-qsbase4.env
    └── u-boot-karo_2022.04.bbappend
```

The file structure of the layer's recipe I am trying to append is this:

```
.
├── imx-atf
│   ├── imx-atf-2.6
│   │   └── patches
│   ├── imx-atf_2.6.bb
│   └── imx-atf_2.6.bbappend
├── imx-mkimage
│   ├── imx-boot-karo_1.0.bb
│   ├── imx-boot-karo_%.bbappend
│   ├── imx-mkimage_git.inc
│   └── mkimage
│       ├── 0001-iMX8M-soc.mak-use-native-mkimage-from-sysroot.patch
│       ├── cleanup.patch
│       ├── imx8qxb0-bugfixes.patch
│       ├── make-clean-bugfix.patch
│       ├── make-dependencies.patch
│       ├── mkimage-fit-atf-bugfixes.patch
│       ├── mx9-nxp-bsp
│       ├── no-tee.patch
│       └── tx8m-support.patch
├── imx-vpu-hantro-vc
│   └── imx-vpu-hantro-vc_%.bbappend
├── isp-imx
│   ├── imx219
│   │   ├── 0001-isp-imx-add-imx219.patch
│   │   └── 0002-isp-imx-make-imx219-default.patch
│   └── isp-imx_%.bbappend
└── u-boot
    ├── u-boot-karo-2022.04
    │   ├── cfg
    │   ├── defconfigs
    │   ├── dts
    │   ├── env
    │   └── karo.bmp
    ├── u-boot-karo_2022.04.bb
    └── u-boot-karo_2022.04.bbappend
```

As you can see, there are more files here, however, I am only trying to modify the files inside the .env. folder for now.

This is my layer.conf file:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*.bbappend "

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-sri"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-sri = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-sri = "6"

LAYERDEPENDS_meta-sri = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-sri = "langdale"
```

My problem is: When I bitbake, the changes are not reflected on the u-boot directory inside the
`build/tmp/work/...../git/` directory.

Would anyone know what could be wrong with my bbappend?